# Pulling Key values from VBA dictionary

Tags: vba, excel

I have identified unique values in a list of data by the method I have abbreviated below:

```
Dim dictionary as scripting.dictionary
Dim data() as String
Dim dataSize as Integer
Dim j as integer
Dim v as variant

DataSize = myRange.Rows.Count

Redim data(dataSize)
For j = 1 to UBound(data)
data(j) = myRange.Cells(j,1).Value
dictionary(data(j)) = 1
Next j
```

This should be storing the unique values from myRange as the Key values. However, I can't seem to figure out how to access the values. I have tried the following:

```
For each v in dictionary.Keys()
myVar = v
'dostuff to myVar
next v
```

and

```
For each v in dictionary.Keys()
myVar = dictionary.Keys(v)
'dostuff to myVar
next v
```

but neither works. What am I missing?

Comment: The `myVar = v` method will work.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I posted what did work below.

Comment: Missing indentation, for one thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Set dictionary = New dictionary`  and then you can loop through:

```
Sub t()
Dim dictionary     As Scripting.dictionary
Dim data()  As String
Dim dataSize As Integer
Dim j       As Integer
Dim v       As Variant

dataSize = myRange.Rows.Count
Set dictionary = New dictionary

ReDim data(dataSize)
For j = 1 To UBound(data)
    data(j) = myRange.Cells(j, 1).Value
    dictionary(data(j)) = 1
Next j

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To dictionary.Count - 1
    Debug.Print dictionary.Keys()(i) & " " & dictionary.Items()(i)
Next i
End Sub
```